# How do I make the "Text contains" evaluate multiple values in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I want the cell to be formatted if the cell contains any of the following words: blue, orange, red, green, and white. I also want to not make 5 different commands for each (this is because I have a loooong list in my actual file).

The entry `blue|orange|red|green|white` does not seem to work; nor does the entry `blue OR orange OR red OR green OR white`. How do I do this?

Comment: Tags should not be forced into titles. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 21):

IMO better without "Text contains".

To avoid the possibility of conflicting rules, clear all conditional formatting from ColumnA (**assumed** because OP does not say where the data is), select it and apply a **Custom formula is** of:

```
=regexmatch(A1,"blue|green|orange|red|white")
```

Select your formatting and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

This will format `blue-green` as well as `blue` and `Red car` as well as `red`, but also `coloured`.

If to format only cells that contain the selected colour names (and nothing else, not for example `White paper`), try:

```
=match(A1,{"blue","green","orange","red","white"},0)
```

For your locale you might need `;` rather than `,`.

[REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).

[MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).

Comment: thanks, but what the "A1" stand for? (`=RegExMatch(A2;"xx")` applies the formating to the cell above, why?)

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula for conditional formatting, like

```
 =MATCH(<cell>, {"blue", "orange", "red", "green", "white"}, 0)
```